# splitting and joining words in a string to remove extra spaces in between words

Tags: python, split

I'm fairly new to python, so I'm trying to take a string with two words that could be a mix of upper and lower case separated by 1 or more spaces (like in my example with the variable name) and turn it into a string like
"Banana Split", where the first letter of each word is in caps and the rest are lower, spaces removed except for one in between the two words. Here's what I got:

```
name = "banAna   sPlit"
name = name.lower()
name = name.split()
for i in name: 
   i = i[0].upper() + i[1:] 

name = " ".join(i)

print(name)
```

Why does this only split the first word? Doesn't the for loop address each element of the list, which contains "banana" and "split"? How should I fix this?

Comment: It does ‘address’ each element if you want to use that word. If you mean does it update each element, then no it doesn’t.

Comment: When you assign to `i` you're just assigning to the variable, not the list element it got its value from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `title()` function!

```
name = "banAna   sPlit"
name = name.lower()
name = name.split()

array = []
for i in name: 
    array.append(i.title())

name = " ".join(array)

print(name)
```

This also removes the whitespace between words!

Comment: Didn't know about that function. Thanks! What about if there were words (such as conjunctions) that should not be capitalized in a title? Such as in "United States of America", the of remains lowercase for both its letters.

Comment: @d784 I belive that you can add simple if statement into the for loop. Tell me if you need help with that one!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list with the adjustments you are looking for.

```py
name = "banAna   sPlit"
name = name.lower()
name = name.split()
name =  [i[0].upper() + i[1:] for i in name] 

name = " ".join(name)

print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` takes on the value of the element, but assigning to `i` will reassign the variable, and not assign to the value of the list. Instead, `enumerate` the list so you get an index and a value, then assign the new value to the list with the index:

```py
for i, v in enumerate(name):
    name[i] = v[0].upper() + v[1:]

name = " ".join(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to `i` doesn't assign to the list element, it just assigns to the variable.

Use a list comprehension to create a new list with the modifications.

```
name = [i[0].upper() + i[1:] for i in name]
name = " ".join(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes into account more than two spaces

```
name = "banAna   sPlit"
names = name.split(' ')
names = str([" ".join(filter(None,names))]).title()

print(names)

>>> ['Banana Split']
```